# With no Key file or seed, is it impossible to recover account/coins

Tags: wallet-recovery

After a series of appallingly stupid events, all my own fault, trying to place certain files on an external hard drive, then deleting them and downloading a "fresh" installation, I no longer have my seed or my key file, even after trying data recovery software. I have an account with coins inside it, is there any other way to restore the wallet / get access to my coins? I would greatly appreciate any help, I'll give a phone number if anyone wants to talk me through it and I'll pay someone for their time. I desperately need to get back into this account, I have all details and even proof of transactions going into it and out of it.

Many thanks,

Dave.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have your seed words and cannot recover your wallet's key file from the disk you deleted them from, the only other option is a brute-force attempt, which isn't even worth trying as it will take too long.

Think about it, if there *was* a way to do what you're asking, everybody's funds would be at risk of theft.

Comment: I thought as much, I'm currently trying a deep scan with Disk Drill overnight to see if that miraculously produces the .key file. Could you personally recommend any other form of "brute-force" attempts at data recovery?